# htaccess delete and ban all extensions and add / to the end of the URL

Tags: .htaccess, content-management-system

I am making a small cms in php. Through htaccess I would like to delete and block all extensions (.php .html. Htm etc.) and add a / at the end of the url.
ex. www.miosito/ article-name/

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex home.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ core.php
```

this is my current htaccess.
Sorry for my bad English and thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your shown samples/attempts, could you please try following htaccess Rules file. Please make sure to clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Excluding Indexes and MultiViews options here.
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

##Rule for url http://localhost:80/test here.
RewriteRule ^(test)/?$ $1/category [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(test/category)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

##Rule for forbidding html OR htm OR php extension files.
RewriteRule \.(html|php|Htm)/?$ - [F,NC,L]

##Rule for adding / at end of urls.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

##Rules for non-existing pages to be served here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ core.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems to work, but unfortunately only partially. I can remove the file extension and add the /, but unfortunately that's not what I was trying to do. I try to explain myself better: if I have an about.php page, with the posted code it does not allow me to access the page. Actually what I would like to do is the same thing that wordpress does. ex. sitename/name-article/ or sitename/about/

Comment: @angeloD83, Could you please do mention sample URL what you are hitting? eg--> `http://localhost:80/blabla`? And which file should serve that URL in backend? Thank you.

Comment: currently the URL is http://localhost/tes /
I would like to access the category.php page
but I get http://localhost/test/category/ and it won't let me access the file.
Category.php is located in the folder /tes / the latter is the root folder.

Comment: @angeloD83, Could you please try my updated htaccess Rules file once? I have added rules to redirect from `http://localhost:80/test` to `http://localhost:80/test/category.php`. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @angeloD83, could you please do let me know if rules have worked for you?

Comment: I did several tests, but unfortunately I was unable to get the script to work as I wanted. I think I'll have to give up.

Comment: @angeloD83, please do let me know what sample URL you are hitting and what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I was partially able to get the code posted by you to work. Unfortunately the only thing that currently gives me problems is the removal of the file extension. If I set the extension to be removed, the forbidden page is always visualized.

Comment: @angeloD83, I could help you if you could give me samples of for which file extensions you want to hide?

Comment: for example: I would like to access the category.php page, typing "sitename/category/" but I would like to prohibit access to the page using the url "sitename/category.php

Comment: @angeloD83, rules `##Rule for url http://localhost:80/test here.
RewriteRule ^(test)/?$ $1/category [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(test/category)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]` are for same only, what you are seeing now? When you hit `http://localhost:80/test/category`? It should work IMHO.

Comment: ok, adding the code posted earlier works. But when I add 'RewriteRule \. (Html ​​| php | Htm) /? $ - [F, NC, L]', all pages show "forbidden".

Comment: @angeloD83, but that's what you have told no, to forbid all urls having html or htm or php hit directly in browser, please do let me know which url you are hitting and which is not working.

Comment: @angeloD83, could you please provide information asked in my previous comment, I believe we are very near by to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code in site root .htaccess after completely clearing your browser cache:

```sh
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex home.php
RewriteEngine On

# block direct access to .php, .html, .html extensions files
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.(html?|php)[?\s/] [NC]
RewriteRule . - [F]

## Adding a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,NE,R=301]

# core handler
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . core.php [L]
```